# didHighlightRowAt in RxSwift

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift, frp

How do I implement `didHighlightRowAt` (`UITableViewDelegate`) in RxSwift? I could find most of the delegate methods but I could not find `didHighlightRowAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way?

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITableView {

    var didHighlightRowAt: ControlEvent<IndexPath> {
        let selector = #selector(UITableViewDelegate.tableView(_:didHighlightRowAt:))
        let events = delegate
            .methodInvoked(selector)
            .filter({ ($0.last as? IndexPath) != nil })
            .map({ $0.last as! IndexPath })
        return ControlEvent(events: events)
    }
}

let observable = UITableView().rx.didHighlightRowAt.asObservable()
```